# Is it possible to use different from email in contact form 7 with different domain?

Tags: email, plugin-contact-form-7, hosting

https://prnt.sc/v7mwif

I need to know how can we setup the different email on different host.

my site name is tailwindimaging.com and I want to send email from xxx@tailwindimagery.com

But I'm getting the error as per the above screenshot.

How can I fix it?

Comment: As long as your outbound mail system is happy with it that should be fine. At first glance I can't see any obvious hooks in CF7 to disable this validation, so you might have to comment out the code yourself for now ([here](https://github.com/takayukister/contact-form-7/blob/v5.3/includes/config-validator.php#L463)) and maybe ask CF7 directly if there's a better solution.

Comment: I guess the 'solve it properly' answer is to add a configurable list of additional email domains and extend the check to allow those too, instead of just commenting it out.

Comment: @rup thank you for the answer, but I have tried this using this filter "add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_configuration', '__return_false' );"

An error has gone but can not receive any email.